Yocto Project: Linking a Shared Library to a Package Results in "library_common.h: No such file or directory" Error
I'm working on a Yocto project and need to create and link a shared library to one of the packages. The directory structure of the shared library source code is as follows:
library
├── svc
│   ├── src
│   │   └── library_common.c
│   ├── inc
│   │   └── library_common.h
├── Makefile.am
├── configure.ac
└── library.pc.in

I've written Makefile.am and configure.ac as shown below:
Makefile.am:
ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS = -I m4

AM_CFLAGS = -Wundef \
            -Wstrict-prototypes \
            -fno-short-enums \
            -fpic \
            -Wall \
            -Wunused

AM_CPPFLAGS = -I$(srcdir)/svc/inc

AM_LDFLAGS = $(TARGET_LDFLAGS) \
             -g \
             -fexceptions \
             -fpie

lib_LTLIBRARIES = liblibrary.la

source_dir = svc/src
header_dir = svc/inc

source_files = $(source_dir)/library_common.c
header_files = $(header_dir)/library_common.h

required_libs = -lpthread -lrt

pkgconfigdir = $(libdir)/pkgconfig
pkgconfig_DATA = library.pc
EXTRA_DIST = $(pkgconfig_DATA)

liblibrary_la_SOURCES = $(source_files) $(header_files)
liblibrary_la_CFLAGS = $(AM_CFLAGS)
liblibrary_la_CPPFLAGS = $(AM_CPPFLAGS)
liblibrary_la_LDFLAGS = $(AM_LDFLAGS) -shared -version-info 1:0:0
liblibrary_la_LIBADD = $(required_libs)

configure.ac:
AC_PREREQ(2.61)
AC_INIT([library], 1.0.0)

AC_CONFIG_AUX_DIR([build-aux])
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([foreign subdir-objects])
AM_MAINTAINER_MODE
AC_CONFIG_SRCDIR([svc/src/library_common.c])
AC_CONFIG_HEADER([config.h])
AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR([m4])
AC_PROG_CC
AC_PROG_LIBTOOL
PKG_PROG_PKG_CONFIG

LT_INIT()

AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile \
                 library.pc])

AC_OUTPUT

library_git.bb:
inherit pkgconfig autotools-brokensep qprebuilt deploy

DESCRIPTION = "library"
HOMEPAGE = "http://support.cdmatech.com"
LICENSE = "****"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "****"

SRC_DIR = "${WORKSPACE}/data/library"
FILESPATH =+ "${WORKSPACE}/data:"
SRC_URI = "file://library/"

S = "${WORKDIR}/library"

# Package Revision (update whenever recipe is changed)
PR = "r1"

I've added the library to the DEPENDS variable in the package BitBake recipe and included $(LIBRARY_CFLAGS) in the bin_CPPFLAGS variable and $(MBOEM_LIBS) in the bin_LDADD variable.
However, when I run bitbake package, I encounter the following error:
| in_some_file:75:10: fatal error: library_common.h: No such file or directory
|    75 | #include "library_common.h"

I've tried various solutions but haven't been able to resolve this issue. Could anyone help me out? Apologies for the lengthy question.

"I've tried various solutions but haven't been able to resolve this issue." Please post your solutions as well, so that it would be easier for other to find out what you already know and things that you've already tried

The diagnostic you're asking about describes an issue with compiling, not linking.

Do you get that error while building the library, or while building the program that depends on it?

And are you bundling the library together with the program, or managing the two as separate components?

Can you also post the recipe where you're using the library? Is the file "library_common.h" present in the work directory of the recipe using the library? (use e.g. find YOUR_BUILD_FOLDER/tmp/work/ -iname YOUR_RECIPE)
